# JAutodoc - add data type of the method params

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, jautodoc

I don't know how to add the data type of the method params ("Integer" in the example below):

Example:

```
@param idTemplate the id template - Integer
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no place for type of data in the javadoc. See documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html#@param.

When you are compiling the Javadoc, the compiler automatically links the types with their `@param` description by their corresponding name.

```
/**
 * @param     a    This is the parameter.
 */
public void foo(int a)
{
...
}
```